# Patch vs merge-patch which is appropriate?

Tags: java, rest, http, jax-rs, http-patch

trying to see which models are best suited for `api` (low updates, but object structure could change often, high read application)

I have a resource like this

1. **Epic** (id, name, description, start date, close date, status,
   **stories**)
2. **Story** (id, name, description, start date, close date, status, **tasks**)
3. **Task** (id, name, description, start date, resolution date,
   resolution)

If I need to support just update of these ,

1. update **Epic** name or description or dates or status
2. update **Story** name or description or dates or status
3. update **Task** name or description or dates or status

which makes sense?

**`PATCH` with `application/merge-patch+json` `RFC 7396`**

the resource should match target object structure

1. epics/{id}
2. epics/{id1}/stories/{id2} .. and so on

**`PATCH` with `application/json`** - **I am inclined to choose this** as there is no need so strictly enforce `RFC 7396` and flexibility to update the rules of updates.

your custom rules to update (but technically - I could just send the resource attributes that needs updates similar to `application/merge-patch+json`)

1. epics/{id}
2. epics/{id1}/stories/{id2} .. and so on

**`PUT` with `application/json`**

the resource should match all fields and create new object and replace (or cheat and just update only like in patch)

1. epics/{id}
2. epics/{id1}/stories/{id2} .. and so on

**`PUT` with `application/json`**

or cheat and just update only like in patch but use put

1. epics/{id}
2. epics/{id1}/stories/{id2} .. and so on

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the perspective of REST, the important thing to keep in mind is the uniform interface -- you have some resource with an `application/json` representation.  I can `GET` your representation, and make local edits to it using whatever my favorite tool might be.

If I then want to propose that the resource should be changed to match my representation, we choose the appropriate method from the HTTP protocol.  In other words, the methods in HTTP are all part of the "transport this document over a network" domain.  (Ref: [Jim Webber, 2011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s)).

So realistically, supporting "all of them" is the way to ensure the widest number of generic clients can be used to interact with your resources.

```
PUT /31E772D3-0157-4B52-8243-75EEAB946E65
Content-Type: application/json
```

Perfectly reasonable starting point; it has a couple of advantages - the semantics are [idempotent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2), so clients know that a lost request can be repeated, and HTTP [PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) includes semantics for important use cases like "we accepted your representation as is" that allow you to reduce network pressure.

PUT may be an unfortunate choice when the representation is much larger than the changes.

```
PATCH /31E772D3-0157-4B52-8243-75EEAB946E65
Content-Type: ????
```

This is a perfectly reasonable way to deal with small changes to large representations.  You give up some of the advantages of PUT - lost messages are now more complicated to deal with.

```
PATCH /31E772D3-0157-4B52-8243-75EEAB946E65
Content-Type: application/json
```

Not at any odds.  `application/json` is not a [patch document](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789#section-2) format -- you have no way of knowing what changes are being described by such a representation without some sort of out-of-band agreement.

```
PATCH /31E772D3-0157-4B52-8243-75EEAB946E65
Content-Type: application/vnd.example.patch+json

PATCH /31E772D3-0157-4B52-8243-75EEAB946E65
Content-Type: application/prs.example.patch+json
```

This is the "REST" way to do the previous bit; you define a custom media type, and document the semantics, and then any client that implements your media type can use it.  The [vendor tree](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6838#section-3.2) and [vanity tree](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6838#section-3.3) are available.  The `+json` bit is the [structured syntax name suffix](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6838#section-4.2.8), which offers a structure hint for consumers that don't recognize the base subtype.

```
PATCH /31E772D3-0157-4B52-8243-75EEAB946E65
Content-Type: application/json-patch+json

PATCH /31E772D3-0157-4B52-8243-75EEAB946E65
Content-Type: application/merge-patch+json
```

Also excellent choices, because these two types have been standardized in [RFC 6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) and [RFC 7936](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7386); you have a much better chance that a client will already know these types.

A client that knows about HTTP [PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) will presumably also know how to use the OPTIONS method to discover what methods and [patch document formats](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789#section-3.7) the server is prepared to handle.

```
OPTIONS /31E772D3-0157-4B52-8243-75EEAB946E65

HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Allow: OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH
Accept-Patch: application/prs.example.patch+json, application/json-patch+json, application/merge-patch+json
```